# Re-order cells in UITableView with swift and fetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have a UITableView in swift where the app allows users to re-order the cells, but it keeps crashing during the re-order.

I have this data model:

```
class Person: NSManagedObject {

@NSManaged var name: String
@NSManaged var mood: String

}
```

I have setup a bool variable to check when the user hits the edit button to see if the tableview.setEdititing is set to true, because this indicates a change in order is about to happen:

```
var userDrivenDataChange : Bool = false
```

Then for each of the fetched results controller delegate methods before I go ahead I always check if there are user driven changees to the object - for example...

```
func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    if userDrivenDataChange{
        return
    }
    tblView.beginUpdates()
}
```

Now, this is the bit I'm really struggling with...

In the moveRowAtIndexPath function, my logic is to get the object the user has just moved, and then get the section that the user wants to move the line to.  Then create a new Person NSManagedObject but set its "mood" field to the new section name, then delete the object at the old indexPath.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath destinationIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    userDrivenDataChange = true

    var context = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate).managedObjectContext!
    var entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Person", inManagedObjectContext: context)
    var secInfo = fetchedResultController.sections![destinationIndexPath.section] as NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo

    var personToAmend = fetchedResultController.objectAtIndexPath(sourceIndexPath) as Person

    var copyOfPerson = Person(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
    copyOfPerson.name = personToAmend.name
    copyOfPerson.mood = secInfo.name!

    context.deleteObject(personToAmend)

    var err : NSError?
    if !context.save(&err){
        println(err)
    }

    userDrivenDataChange = false
}
```

So this doesn't work, honestly can't figure out why!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Jamie

p.s. Just incase you need to see it, my fetched results controller is:

```
lazy var fetchedResultController : NSFetchedResultsController = {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Person")
    let context = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate).managedObjectContext!
    let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "mood", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sort]
    let frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: "mood", cacheName: nil)
    frc.delegate = self
    return frc
}()
```

----EDIT:

When a user reorders rows from one section to another, the fetchedResultsController always adds the row to the beginning of the section instead of the actual index path represented by destinationIndexPath.

So I guess my question becomes: Is there a function to either edit the index Path of the object I insert, or to add an object at a specific index path?

Comment: What line does it crash on and what is the error message?

Comment: ok so I can define the issue a little better now…

Say when a user moves a row from one section to another, the fetchedResultsController always adds the row to the beginning of the section, instead of the actual index path that the user dragged the row to.

So the question now becomes how to insert an object at a specific index Path (more specifically, to destinationIndexPath)